# group a set of rows between 2 varchar values

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL table

```
1   id  mediumint(9)
2   user_id mediumint(9)
3   location_id mediumint(9)
4   timestamp   timestamp
5   activity    varchar(100)
6   points  mediumint(9)
```

I want to query user_id, location_id, date, SUM(points) between (grouped by) 2 different activities (checkin and checkout), but i can't figure out how.
Any activity between checkin and checkout should be allowed.

```
1   38  13  2015-05-13 13:26:01 checkin 100
2   38  13  2015-05-13 13:26:07 add_points  5
3   38  13  2015-05-13 13:26:13 add_points  5
4   38  13  2015-05-13 13:26:19 add_points  5
5   38  13  2015-05-13 13:26:26 add_points  5
6   38  13  2015-05-13 13:26:31 add_points  5
7   38  13  2015-05-13 13:26:37 add_points  5
8   38  13  2015-05-13 13:33:42 checkout    0
```

the result for this set should be:

```
userid   location    date         sum of points between checkin and checkout
38       13          2015-05-13   130
```

when there are more checkin and checkouts, the result should add another row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba90b/2

```
SELECT t.*,
   SUM(t.points)
FROM (
  SELECT *,
   IF(activity='checkin', @gr:=CONCAT(user_id,`timestamp`), @gr) gr,
   IF(activity='checkout', @gr:=null, @gr)
FROM table1
ORDER BY user_id,`timestamp`) t
GROUP BY t.gr
```

Comment: This looks great. I didn't know this. Even with same userid and location it makes a two rows. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c66e/1  Only question left is if there is always a checkout.

Comment: Yes, that was (almost) it, i modified it just a little to get the results i wanted: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b7d8/1

Comment: I would suggest to add another column like `session_id`. It will simplify any queries in future and increase performance. Because the trick I used here is not optimal way to group, especially if table will really grow in future

Comment: Had to add another order by on ID, when there are multiple user_id's in mixed order: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64997/2

Comment: Yes, so my original idea, without this knowledge, was a good one. Thanks!

Comment: @Marijn to add `id` in `ORDER` clause is bad idea. The problem is your bad data (that is why I suggest to add another column to the table). In your data sample you have 2 rows with same `user_id` and `checkin` with same timestamp so now you are lucky and have different id and same points. But in reality it shouldn't ever been such set of data.

Comment: That is correct, the provided data-set was not clean. in reality there can never be a checkin without a checkout. Also, i am always querying with just 1 user-id (it is a user specific log/history). Ordering by user_id & timestamp should be enough. Thanks everyone for the help and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would do, because your also summarizing the points from checkin (100) and checkout (0).

I assumed that userid and location are a unique combination else you have to work with date indeed.

```
SELECT userid
,      location
,      DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d-%Y')
,      sum(points) total_points
FROM table
GROUP BY userid
,        location
,        DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d-%Y');
```

If there are multiple checkin / checkouts with the same userid and location then you can consider to add a column like session to your table or an other unique identifier. It makes it more easier to query. You can use that identifier in your GROUP BY to get the multiple records you would like to have.

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple checkin/checkouts with the same user/location, thats exactly my 'problem' :) Adding another column with a 'session' would make this easier indeed, so i can just group by session. Grouping by date is not an option, since it can be spread across multiple dates. I just think it should be possible to 'group' them without adding another unique session-id, but just group them based on the checkin/checkout values.

Comment: Indeed, that's what i meant. When the user comes back on the same day, the date of both sessions is the same. You must have a purchase number or something that you can use. Using date is not waterproof.

Comment: I tested the solution of @Alex and I learned something new. It looks like if that is the solution

Comment: Jup, though your suggestion would have worked aswell, it was just not the solution i was looking for.